How to Adjust LightGBM Parameters Like `min_child_samples` When Increasing Training Data?
I'm training a LightGBM model and currently facing a dilemma regarding parameter tuning when increasing the amount of training data.
Initially, I split my dataset into 90% for training and 10% for testing. Using grid search, I found the optimal parameters for the model. Now, I want to leverage 100% of the data to train the model to make it as strong as possible.
My question is about parameters like min_child_samples, which is related to the data volume. When I increase the data from 90% to 100%, should I keep min_child_samples the same as the value found during the 90% data training? Or should I adjust it because the data volume has increased?
Could someone provide guidance on how to handle this, or share any best practices?
